# Show that the largest family of pairwise intersecting non crossing partitions, all share the same subset

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

> Show that the largest family of non crossing partitions of any set, in which every pair of members shares some set, is a family in which every member shares *the same* singleton set.

The non crossing (by some ordering) partitions of any set of $n$ elements, are enumerated by $C_{n-1}$ where $C_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Catalan number.

A pair of partitions of the set is intersecting if they share at least one subset.

My answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114646/) proves that every member of the largest family of partitions *all sharing the same subset*, shares the same singleton subset.  This yields the size of the largest such family as $C_{n-2}$, i.e. one Catalan number lower than the entire enumeration.

I'm sure the largest family of non crossing partitions in which *every pair* of family members shares some subset, has this same property - i.e. every member shares the same singleton set but I don't know how to prove it.

What I do know is this:

To show that the largest family of pairwise intersecting, non crossing, partitions is itself an enumeration of all possible non crossing partitions of some set, is sufficient for the proof.

To show that a) the largest $n-2$ face of any associahedron (measured in terms of its number of vertices), has exactly $C_{n-2}$ vertices, and every face of an associahedron corresponds to a family of partitions which all share the same subset, would again be sufficient to prove the conjecture.

If we examine the set of all *possibly crossing* partitions of a set (say there are $m$ of them, we can have $2^m$ possible sets of such partitions including the empty set.  It is clear that the largest family of these which are pairwise intersecting coincides with the largest family all sharing the same singleton, and there are $2^{m-1}$ in number.  The conjecture is that this conjunction is shared by families of non crossing partitions.

By way of illustration, the longest distance we can travel along the Tamari lattice of $C_4=14$ vertices [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Tamari_lattice_T4_Hasse_diagrams#/media/File:Tamari_lattice,_ovals.svg) while holding some subset in common to all pairs, spans $C_3=5$ vertices and is achieved by fixing any singleton across all subsets, as the conjecture stipulates.